# Taking partial derivatives on the TI-89

Tags: calculus

Does anyone know why when you take the partial derivative of say xy using the differentiate function on the TI-89 does it not give you the correct answer?

example
d/dx(xy) = 0 on the calculator

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Does it know it is $\dfrac{d}{dx}(x * y)$ as opposed to thinking it is a single variable?

Answer (score 1):

This was already mentioned as a comment, but just to be clear, in this instance the TI-89 will treat `xy` as a single variable, not as `x*y`.

For example:

`d/dy(x*e^(xy)) = 0` ← variable is interpreted to be $xy$

whereas

`d/dy(x*e^(x*y)) = e^(x*y)*x^2`. ← variables are interpreted to be $x$ and $y$